# Why the extra implode, array_map, etc functions instead of returning simply a string from the start? Trying to move this PHP to node

Tags: php, node.js, arrays, array-map

```
    private static function getOrdering($sortingColumn, $sortingDirection)
    {
        if ($sortingColumn === 'reportTime') {
            return implode(', ', array_map(function ($column) use ($sortingDirection) {
                return $column . ' ' . $sortingDirection;
            }, ['report_date', 'report_hour', 'report_minute']));
        }
        return $sortingColumn . ' ' . $sortingDirection;
    }
```

I'm struggling a bit to understand how the combination of implode and array_map are working. Moreso, what exactly does `array_map(function ($column) use ($sortingDirection)...` mean? The function ($column) (what does this mean, and where does column come from?) is throwing me off a bit. I'm quite new to PHP, so any basic explanation will likely help.

Edit: Apologies. This is far too broad. Perhaps a more pointed question is:
I did try something, but I'm wondering why in the case that the sortingColumn is "reportTime", we don't simply return a concatenation of the "report_date", "report_hour", etc along with the sortingDirection appended to each. Running:

```
$sortingDirection = 'DESC';

echo(implode(' , ', array_map(function ($column) use ($sortingDirection) { return $column . ' ' . $sortingDirection;}, ['report_date', 'report_hour', 'report_minute'])));
```

gives me what I'd think: report_date DESC, report_hour DESC, etc. Why go through the extra steps of implode, array_map, etc when I could just return the appropriate string right from the start?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? https://3v4l.org/PNX1A

Comment: While the dv's on this question may be merited.  This question seems narrow enough to keep open. [How to deal with questions of the type "I don't understand how this code works"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278797/2943403)

Comment: If you want to avoid `implode(array_map())`, then `array_reduce()` can be used.  I agree with Phil, though, it is simpler to read an imploded array versus a multi-concatenated string building process.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification folks. That clears up everything I was curious. I hope my edits to the post made the question more clear if others come across this in the future.

Comment: My opinion is that the the extension of this question's focus has made more work for Phil's answer.  It's kind of unclear if you are seeking php advice or node advice.  I'm not sure why we're talking about node at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the docs for PHP's [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php) should help.

PHP functions have function-scope (not block scope like JavaScript). The `use` keyword is used to pull in outer scoped variables into the anonymous function.

`array_map()` is very similar to `Array.prototype.map()` in JS. It accepts a callback function to execute for each element in the array (`$column` in your example).

The JavaScript equivalent would look something like this...

```js
const getOrdering = (sortingColumn, sortingDirection) => {
  if (sortingColumn === "reportTime") {
    return ["report_date", "report_hour", "report_minute"]
      .map((column) => `${column} ${sortingDirection}`) // array_map()
      .join(", "); // implode()
  }
  return `${sortingColumn} ${sortingDirection}`;
};
```

---

You could definitely return a string with `$sortingDirection` interpolated, eg

```php
return "report_date $sortingDirection, report_hour $sortingDirection, ...";
```

but the issue then is maintainability. Adding, removing or generally altering the list becomes a chore whereas maintaining an array is much simpler. It could even be stored elsewhere say in a configuration file or database.

Comment: @kastaplastislife I've added a note regarding your edit